# How to handle android chrome URL bar pushing down website?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I want my webpage to take up 100% of the height of the user's device without scrolling, but when I use Chrome on Android, the URL bar pushes down my page, and then it has an option to drag up to get the full view.  [image]   I don't want my controls sliding around, how should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used position:fixed to solve this